# If X is Hausdorff and K⊂X is compact then the contraction X/K is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

I found this claim as an answer to one problem. I tried to prove it in the following way: $X$  is Hausdorff so for every $x$ that does not lie in $K$ compact i can find two disjont open set A,B such that $x∈A$ and $K⊂B$. 
[As the space is $T2$ both the point and the compact subspace are closed in $X$].
$A$ and $B$ are saturated so their images through the projection are the disjoint open sets that let $X/K$ be Hausdorff.
Is this proof correct? If not where does it fail? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems correct to me. You do know the proof that for any point and any compact set in a Hausdorff space, they can be separated by open neighborhoods?

Comment: Also, you may have proved that any point is separable by open neighborhoods from the contracted point, but any two points must be separable by open neighborhoods. This should be an easy exercise, given what you have already shown.

Comment: Oh yes I know but I thought it wasn't key as I only need to consider the case in which the intersection between one of the neighborhoods and K is not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is good to show that a point $x\in X\setminus K$ and $\hat{K}$ (the contraction of $K$) are separated in $X/K$.

However this doesn't fully suffice. If $x,y\in X\setminus K$ and $x\ne y$ you have to prove that they can be separated by disjoint open sets.

Choose $A$ and $B$ as before for $x$, but also $A'$ and $B'$ for $y$ in the same way. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, you can conclude. Fill in the details.

---

How do you prove the key fact? For every $z\in K$ choose $U_z$ and $V_z$ disjoint open sets containing $x$ and $z$ respectively. Then $(V_z)_{z\in K}$ is an open cover of $K$ and so there are $z_1,\dots,z_n$ such that $B=V_{z_1}\cup\dots\cup V_{z_n}\supseteq K$. Take $A=U_{z_1}\cap\dots\cap U_{z_n}$.

Comment: Yes I thought that once you show it works for any point in outside K and K it follows easily for the other points.
For the proof of the key fact i had already worked it out.